# «Каралька колбасы» — как она выглядит? Этимология

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, значение-слов, диалектизмы

Услышала недавно в новом магазине (честное слово, совершенно случайно!).

*— Что купила? Да ничего особенного: хлебушка, фруктов и **каральку колбасы.***

Никогда не сталкивалась со словом "каралька". Нашла в Викисловаре:
[**кара́лька**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0) — ***рег.*** витая булка; бублик, крендель, рогалик.

Правильно ли так говорить — *каралька колбасы*? Как же она выглядит?
Какова этимология слова? Где оно распространено? Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: К сожалению, в оцифрованных письменных источниках это слово не ищется никак. В [Национальном корпусе русского языка](http://ruscorpora.ru/new/search-main.html) удаётся найти **единственный пример** 2004 года. И этот же самый источник, на который ссылается и Викисловарь — статья «Свадьба тюменских старожилов» в журнале «Народное творчество», №5, 2004г.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь https://tavria-rus.ru/catalog/polukopchenye_kolbasy_kralki/
«мясной кралькой» называют связанную в колечко колбаску. Ассоциируется с устойчивым «катись колбаской…».

А тут https://vkusnoidoma.ru/vypechka/kak-iz-tvoroga-prigotovit-karalechki.html
учат готовить «каралечки» из творога. Форма такой каралечки – то же колечко.

Похоже, что «каралька» и есть «кралька», т.е. - колечко/рогалик.